Does the nearest convex function preserve pointwise ordering
You have a set of data points $(x_i, y_i)$, $i=1,2,...,n$ with $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$. The graph formed by these points is not necessarily convex. We thus determine values $w_1, w_2, ..., w_n$ such that the graph formed by $(x_1, w_1),(x_2, w_2),...,(x_n, w_n)$ is convex and the squared difference $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - w_i)^2$ is minimum. This can be achieved via quadratic optimisation.
Assume now that we have other values $y^*_1, y^*_2, \dots, y^*_n$ such that $y_1 \leq y^*_1,  y_2 \leq y^*_2, \dots, y^*_n < y_n$. As before, we determine values $w^*_1, w^*_2, ..., w^*_n$ such that the graph formed by $(x_1, w^*_1),(x_2, w^*_2),...,(x_n, w^*_n)$ is convex and the squared difference $\sum_{i=1}^n(y^*_i - w^*_i)^2$ is minimum.
My question is whether it holds that $w_1 \leq w^∗_1, w_2 \leq w^∗_2, \cdots, w_n \leq w^*_n$.
If we would have imposed increasingness of the graph instead of convexity (as we do here) then this question reads as showing that isotonic regression preserves pointwise ordering and I believe that results on the characterisation of solutions to this problem imply that in this case the answer is positive. I have no clear idea whether it holds for the case I consider here. Any hint, idea or counterexample is useful. If something can be said assuming that the values $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$ and $y^*_1, y^*_2, \dots, y^*_n$ are increasingly ordered then this is of interest too.

"$x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$ . The graph formed by these points is not necessarily convex." what do you mean?

@GBmath $(0,0), (1,1), (2,0)$ does not form a convex graph of a function.

@copper.hat thank you for the explanation! The conjecture sounds correct

@copper.hat Thank you for your answer. Very clear and instructive.

Here is a counterexample for $n=3$.
Take $x_k = k$ for $k=1,2,3$ and let $C = \{ w | \text{graph formed from } (x_k, w_k) \text{ is convex} \}$. Note that $w$ corresponds to a convex function iff $w_2-w_1 \le w_3-w_2$, or equivalently, $C = \{ w | f^T w \le 0 \}$, where $f^T = (-1, 2 -1)$. Hence the problem is
$\min_{w \in W} \|w-y\|_2^2$, or equivalently, the optimal $w$ is given by $w^*(y) = \operatorname{proj}_W y$.
If $y \notin C$, then the constraint must be active, and so the optimal $w^*(y)$ is given by the projection onto the hyperplane $f^T w = 0$. The solution is straightforward to compute and is given by
$w^*(y) = y-{1 \over \|f\|_2^2} f^T f y = Py$, and
$P = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 5 & 2 \\ -1 & 2 & 5\end{bmatrix}$. In particular, note that ${\partial [w^*(y)]_1 \over \partial y_3} = -1$ and so $[w^*(y)]_1$ will decrease when $y_3$ is increased.
For a specific example, with $w^*((0,6,0)^T) = (2,2,2)^T$ and $w^*((0,6,6)^T) = (1,4,7)^T$.

I do not understand that.  In your specific example, what are $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_1,y^_1),(x_2,y^_2),(x_3,y^_3)$ and the corresponding $(x_1,w_1),(x_2,w_2),(x_3,w_3)$ and $(x_1,w^_1),(x_2,w^_2),(x_3,w^_3)$?

@Henry $x_1=1, x_2 = 2, x_3=3$ for all the examples. $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)==(0,6,0)^T$, $w=(2,2,2)^T$, $y^* = (0,6,6)^T$ and $w^* = (1,4,7)^T$. (Numbers chosen so the solutions are integers.) Point being that $y \le y^$, but $w^_1 < w_1$.

Thank you.  It looks as if your example starts with a concave graph which forces the optimal convex approximation to be linear, and then uses leverage of the final point to move the beginning of the line in the desired direction.
